# Using Regex within a custom JS variable to extract part of a string when subsequent characters can be different

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function that I am using to extract part of the URL of a page that is of interest to me:

```
function() {
 var page = {{Page Path}};
 return page.match(/[REGEX]/);
}
```

I need to return the 'match' part of the string from the following URL's:

```
/abc/def/match123

/abc/def/matchxyz

/abc/def/match000
```

I am struggling to do this when the preceding and subsequent character sets can differ. There are only three possible sets of subsequent character sets after the string I want to match: `xyz|123|000` but the preceding can be anything, although always ends with the final `/` in the URL.

Comment: You can try this site, here you can create regex based on your parameters https://regex101.com/.

Comment: So, you want a regex that'll match `match(xyz|123|000)` where "match" can be anything, but it'll always be in the end of the string?

Comment: I want it to match 'match'. The issue is that I want it to stop (and not include) the end of the URL, which can be any of these three: xyz, 123 or 000. I think I have worked it out with this? .*\/(.*?)(xyz|123|000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match the "match" part in replacement-var `$1`:

```
([^\/]+)(123|xyz|000)$
```

To break it down, this will match any character, that is not a `/`, which is immediately followed by on of the accepted patterns. The `$` will require it to be in the end of the string - that could probably be removed, depending on your needs.

Example usage:

```
'/abc/def/iAmTheMatchxyz'.replace(/([^\/]+)(123|xyz|000)$/g, '$1') === 'iAmTheMatch';
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this solution and it seems to work also: /.*\/(.*?)(xyz|123|000)/g any obvious advantage with your solution?

Comment: No obvious advantages, except maybe readability - but that's subjective. I'm not an expert in regex performance, so I can't say if one performs better than the other.